# count character length from a large file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to find character length from a file containing 140000 lines, each string length varies.

```
aaaaa
bbb
ccccc
ddddd
fff
```

Expecting output as below

```
strings char-length
2       3
3       5
```

(means 2 strings character length is 3, 3 strings character length is 5). I have already tried for-loop, which reads each and every line, but it takes time since my file had 140000 string lines.

Comment: Please do add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your own problem in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have awk available you can try the following command:

```
awk '{ print length($0) }' <your_file> | sort | uniq -c
```

(Took 27ms on my VM with sample test file of 7000 lines, each line around 10 chars long).